# Ruby Scripting- How to run a client and server program simultaneously and collect server output

Tags: ruby, scripting, client-server

all. I'm trying to create a ruby script that initializes and runs a server program in the background (usually always running), and then runs a short client program once, then kills the server. Both the server and client are made in C++, and the server runs on localhost, port 4712. The port is a command line argument to the server. The server must be initialized with a "./init_serv" executable, and once it starts running, it must be fed "user1 password1" through cin. I want the output of server collected into a file, "out.txt".
This is what I have so far:

```
require 'open3'

userinput = "user1 password1"
outfile = File.new("out.txt","w+")
system("./init_server")
Open3.popen2("./server.exe 4712") do |stdin, stdout, t|    
    stdin.puts(userinput)
    stdin.close
    stdout.each_line { |line| outfile.write(line) }
end


puts "Server now running"
system("./test_client localhost 4712")
Process.kill("SIGINT", t.pid)
```

I thought that the "popen2" call would make a new thread to run the server program, but when I run this, the program blocks (the server doesn't exit unless manually killed) and never prints the "Server now running" statement. Any suggestions on how to solve this? I'm fairly new to scripting in general, so other advice is appreciated too.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It sounds like you know what you need to do: Create a `thread`. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_multithreading.htm

Comment: Then what exactly does the "t" signify in that code up there? I thought that _was_ the new thread. Is the main thread trying to join it before moving on or something?

Comment: I think you have an extra `end` in there and `w+` is missing the surrounding quotes. Presumably this is just a sketch of code?

Comment: If you're making blocking calls you'll need a background thread to avoid blocking the whole process.

Comment: Right, the exact code is a little bit different because of some irrelevant details; I"ll edit that mistake. But I think you answered my question. The server code's main thread is running a while(1){accept...} loop somewhere,. That means that it will block the rest of the process?

Comment: Side note: You can use `loop do ....` instead of `while(1) do ....`

Comment: The server program is making the blocking call; it's in C++, not ruby. This is the only ruby script I'm running.

Answer (score 0):

Problem's been solved by creating a new thread, as Tom Lord suggested.
This is the new code:

```
require 'open3'

$userinput = "user1 password1"
$outfile = File.new("out.txt","w+")
$processthread = nil
system("./init_server")
thr = Thread.new{
    Open3.popen2("./server.exe 4712") do |stdin, stdout, t|    
        $processthread = t
        stdin.puts($userinput)
        stdin.close
        stdout.each_line { |line| $outfile.write(line) }
        t.join
    end
}

sleep(0.25)
puts "Server now running"
system("./test_client localhost 4712 > clientOut.txt")
Process.kill("SIGINT", $processthread.pid)
Thread.kill(thr)
```

To share data between the outer function and thread, I just lazily used global variables. And the sleep(0.25) lets the socket be properly initialized. Kind of a hacky solution, but it works!
Thanks for the help in the comments.